# What is the history on how previous soft forks were tested prior to being considered for activation?

Tags: testnet, history, soft-fork, testing, signet

How were previous soft forks tested prior to being considered for activation? Were they added to the default testnet? Was a custom testnet setup with the soft fork functionality available on that custom testnet? Were they tested on a sidechain like Liquid? I know we have signet now (generally considered to be superior to today's testnet) but that is a relatively recent development. It was available for Taproot but none of the previously activated soft forks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJ Towns answered this on the bitcoin-dev [mailing list](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2022-October/020964.html).

> - p2sh was briefly tested on testnet (and an alternative was tested on    mainnet)
>   https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=58579.msg786939#msg786939
> - cltv and csv were mostly tested on elements alpha (liquid precursor
>   testnet); though they were activated on testnet 6 and 11 weeks prior
>   to mainnet
>   http://diyhpl.us/wiki/transcripts/gmaxwell-sidechains-elements/
> - segwit was also tested via elements alpha, though in a different
>   form to what was deployed for bitcoin (ie, the elements approach
>   would have been a hard fork). because of the p2p changes (you need
>   additional data to validate blocks post segwit), segwit had dedicated
>   test networks, up to segnet4, from 1st Jan 2016 to 30th Mar 2016.
>   segwit was activated on testnet on 13th May 2016, merged into core on
>   25th June 2016, and included in the 0.13.1 released on 27th October
>   2016. I couldn't find very good public references about segnet, and    don't think it saw much use outside of people implementing segwit
>   consensus features themselves.
> - taproot was merged 15th October 2020 (#18267), and activated on
>   signet as of genesis around 21st October 2020 (#20157). It was locked
>   in on mainnet on 12th June 2021, activated on testnet on 8th July
>   2021, and activated on mainnet on 14th November 2021.
> - CTV had ctv-signet created around 17th December 2020, but it wasn't
>   really announced or encouraged until 17th Feb 2022. The core PR
>   (#21702) was opened 16th April 2021.
>   https://www.erisian.com.au/bitcoin-core-dev/log-2020-12-17.html#l-845
>   https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2022-February/019925.html
> - I think Drivechains has a DriveNet testnet (since 2018 or
>   earlier?),    though I don't see an explorer, and it looks like the
>   bitcoin code    it's based on predates taproot.
> - Other than CTV, Drivechains and ideas being explored on Liquid,
>   most other ideas for bitcoin consensus changes haven't really
>   progressed past a gist, mailing list post, bip or draft patch    to
>   somewhere that you can actually experiment (great consensus
>   cleanup, anyprevout, OP_TX/TXHASH, TLUV, SIGHASH_GROUP, PUSH_ANNEX,
>   checkblockatheight, g'root/graftroot, etc...)
>
> I thing segnet was mostly used for development of segwit itself,
> rather than testing or application development -- it was reset about
> once a month as changes to the segwit design occurred, and after the
> design was finalised, was active on testnet, either using -addnode to
> connect directly to know segwit-enabled peers, or, eventually, with
> seed nodes updated and filtering via the WITNESS feature. The 23rd
> June 2016 meeting logs have some relevant discussion:
> https://www.erisian.com.au/bitcoin-core-dev/log-2016-06-23.html#l-178